# Filter strings that have a symbol appear certain times

Tags: python, string

How to make a condition that accepts only in a loop strings that have '_' only two times.

```
a = ['q_s_e','s_e_v_e','s_v']# many more like these
```

in the above list only the fist item should used in the loop:

```
for i in a:
    if '_' in i:
         ...
```

this takes everything.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [count](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/count) function from string:

```
a = ['q_s_e','s_e_v_e','s_v']
for i in a:
    if i.count('_') == 2:
      print ('hooray')
```

> In simple words, count() method searches the substring in the given
>   string and returns how many times the substring is present in it.
>
> It also takes optional parameters start and end to specify the
>   starting and ending positions in the string respectively.
>
> The syntax of count() method is:
>
> string.count(substring, start=..., end=...)

Another way is to filter the array of string at the beginning as well:

```
a = ['q_s_e','s_e_v_e','s_v']
for i in filter(lambda k: k.count('_') == 2, a):
    print ('hooray')
```

Comment: what do you  mean at the beginning in the second code. isn't it for your first code too?

Comment: The second code sample in other way of reaching the OP desire. @user51332

Comment: You mean without the if?

Comment: @user51332 yes. You filter out the un-relevant items from the list.

Comment: If you want to proceed with more processes which is better the first or the second?

Comment: @user51332, what do you mean more processes? please explain. But basically it does not really matter, just go with what feels more convenient to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) and iterate over a generator expression:

```
for i in (el for el in a if el.count('_') == 2):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that with a conditional using the `count()` method:

```
for item in list:
    if item.count('_') == 2:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex`, this will return the list you want:

```
filtered_list = [e for e in old_list if re.match('^[^_]*(_[^_]*){2}$', e)]
```

Regex `^[^_]*(_[^_]*){2}$` will make sure each of these element contains exactly 2 `_`

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this with `numpy` and remove your loop:

```
arr = np.array(['q_s_e','s_e_v_e','s_v'])
new_arr = arr[np.where(np.char.count(arr, "_") == 2)[0]]
```